# Postgres array of json, get all the unique values of a specific key

Tags: postgresql, unique, jsonb

I have a table that has data like:

```
id, array_json
123, [{"Name": "John", "Age": "12"}, {"Name": "Jane", "Age": "18"}, {"Name": "Jake", "Age": "34"}]
124, [{"Name": "Dolly", "Age": "12"}, {"Name": "Molly", "Age": "18"}, {"Name": "Rosa", "Age": "34"}]
123, []
125, [{"Name": "Dolly", "Age": "12"}, {"Name": "Dolly", "Age": "18"}, {"Name": "Holt", "Age": "34"}]
```

Its basically an id mapped to an array of jsons, which is a jsonb.
I want the output to be all the unique names (Key is "Name") & their count as follows:

```
id, Unique_Names, Count
123, ["John", "Jane", "Jake"], 3
124, ["Dolly", "Molly", "Rosa"], 3
125, [], 0
126, ["Dolly", "Holt"], 2
```

How do I do this in postgres?

Comment: I cannot understand, why do you save JSON data into a postgresql field (?) while there are function in control language (e.g. php) to convert JSON <-> arrray (!). Postgresql does have string function, but it is definitely not a language mainly for string manipulation.

Comment: @schweik Postgres has a jsonb type which is essentially to store jsons.

Comment: It is your decision, but not an answer to my question. In case you need to store JSON data only, you found a perfect solution, but if you want to analyse the dadta stored in JSON object, I recommend to take a standard way. Howg

Answer (score 4):

You need to unnest and then aggregate back:

```
select t2.id
       t2.names as unique_names, 
       jsonb_array_length(names) as count 
from (
  select t.id, 
         (select jsonb_agg(distinct e.val ->> 'Name' order by e.val ->> 'Name') 
          from jsonb_array_elements(t.array_json) as e(val)) as names
  from the_table t
) AS t2
order by t2.id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5c3120dc8fa85c56936a3283aa334582)

Comment: Wrap it as a subquery to get the `Count` column